# How to convert Simplified Chinese characters to html escape characters with Python?

Tags: python, html-escape-characters

I want to get the html escape characters from Simplified Chinese (GB18030).

I tried using the Python library `html.escape` but it does not work.

For example, `宁波` to `%C4%FE%B2%A8` and `江北` to `%BD%AD%B1%B1`.

How to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't want HTML-escaping, you want URL-encoding. Look there.

Comment: Thank you very much, Tomalak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import urllib
urllib.parse.quote('宁波', encoding='GB18030') == '%C4%FE%B2%A8'#True
urllib.parse.quote('江北', encoding='GB18030') == '%BD%AD%B1%B1'#True
```